# React Recharts data with array

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have an array of data with the following structure:

```
0:
  date: '01-12-2020',
  data: Array(2)
    {name: "plants", count: 5}
    {name: "water", count: 2}
1:
  date: '02-12-2020',
  data: Array(2)
    {name: "plants", count: 1}
    {name: "water", count: 4}
...
```

I would like to show the dates on the x-axis and render a line for each `name' category. In this case two lines, one for plants and one for water.

Should I format this code or can I use this array directly in recharts? I'm creating the array myself in the backend so I can also format it there.

I've tried something like this but it is not working:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={200}>
                <LineChart data={data}>
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                    <XAxis dataKey="x" />

                    <YAxis />
                    <Tooltip />
                    {data.map((item, i) => (
                        <Line
                            dataKey={data[0].data[0].count}
                            type="monotone"
                            stroke={colors[0]}
                            activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
                        />
                    ))}
                </LineChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to be formatted into this :

[{name: '01-12-2020',
plants: 5
water : 4}]

you can do as following :

```js
   let result = [];
   data.map(entry) => {
   let obj = {date: entry.date}
     entry.data.map((entry1) => {
      obj[entry1.name] = entry1.count;
    });
   result.push(obj)
  })
```

and your chart as following (your dataKey on XAxis is false)

```
<ChartContainer>
  <ResponsiveContainer>
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      style={{ color: scoopBlue }}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <Legend />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="plants"
        stroke={scoopBlue}
        strokeWidth={2}
        activeDot={{ r: 5 }}
      />
        <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="water"
        stroke={"orange"}
        strokeWidth={2}
        activeDot={{ r: 5 }}
       />
     </LineChart>
   </ResponsiveContainer>
</ChartContainer>
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are using the new `result` array on the LineChart. Where does item.name come from when it is not a property? Can you add clarity to this?

Comment: I corrected my post